# Running Spark sbt project without sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I have a Spark project which I can run from sbt console.  However, when I try to run it from the command line, I get *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkContext*.  This is expected, because the Spark libs are listed as *provided* in the *build.sbt*.

How do I configure things so that I can run the JAR from the command line, without having to use sbt console?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly to build a jar with all dependencies.

Comment: @lpeipiora - I'm indeed using sbt-assembly, but the spark jars are marked as `provided` and thus not included in the assembly

Comment: Can you post your example build and I can help you with an answer?

My guess is some "compile->provided" magic specifiers will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run Spark stand-alone you need to build a Spark assembly.
Run `sbt/sbt assembly` on the spark root dir. This will create: `assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar`

Then you build your job jar with dependencies (either with sbt assembly or maven-shade-plugin)

You can use the resulting binaries to run your spark job from the command line:

```
ADD_JARS=job-jar-with-dependencies.jar SPARK_LOCAL_IP=<IP> java -cp spark-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar:job-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.jobs.SparkJob
```

Note: If you need other HDFS version, you need to follow additional steps before building the assembly. See [About Hadoop Versions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/index.html#a-note-about-hadoop-versions)

Answer (score 2):

Using `sbt assembly plugin` we can create a single jar. After doing that you can simply run it using `java -jar` command

[For more details refer](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/)